# How to prove an equality involving Laguerre polynomials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, integration

Assume  $\mu<0$.  Let $L^\alpha_n(x)$ be Laguerre polynomials of type $n$ and $f\in L^2(\Bbb C)$.

How to prove that $$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\int_{\Bbb C} f(z)\frac{1}{2(2k+1)-\mu}L^0_k(\lvert z\rvert^2)e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2\over 2}dz= \int_{\Bbb C} \sum^\infty_{k=0}f(z)\frac{1}{2(2k+1)-\mu}L^0_k(\lvert z\rvert^2)e^{-\lvert z\rvert^2\over 2}dz$$
where $dz$ is the usual Lebesgue measure? We recall that  $\int^{+\infty}_{0}  \lvert  L^{\alpha}_{k}(t) \rvert^{2}t^{\alpha}e^{-t}dt=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)}$.

We also have $\Gamma(a)\psi\left(  a,c,x\right)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{n+a} L^{c-1}_{n}(x)$ where
$$\Gamma(a)\psi\left(  a,c,x\right)= e^x \int^1_0 \exp(-{x\over 1-t}) t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-1}\in L^2(\Bbb R)  .$$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901995/any-reference-for-%24-%5Cgamma%28a%29-u%28a%2Cb%2Cz%29-%3D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bj%2Ba%7D-l%5E%7Bb-1%7D_%7Bj%7D%28z%29-%24
Thanks in advance

Comment: it is $z$ not $w$ see again. Thank you

Comment: By $dz$ you mean $dxdy$, where $z=x+iy$?

Comment: $z=(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ so $dz=dxdy$ @Fedor Petrov.

Comment: Usually $dz$ is used for contour integration, where it has another sense

Comment: Since you are performing a volume integration in $\Bbb C$, you should use the notation $\mathrm{d}z\wedge\mathrm{d}\bar{z}$ which is a multiple of $\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d} y$.

Comment: Well, for the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and  $f\in \mathcal L^1(\mathcal R^n)$ we do use the notation $\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)dx$, where the dimension of the measure is clear from the domain rather than from "$dx$". So  $\int_{\mathbb C} f(z)dz$ is not out of this word; I don't see a big danger of confusion with a path integral  $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$.